# How to use graphic URLs with Qualtrics Advanced Format files

Tags: qualtrics

I'm trying to import a few thousand questions into Qualtrics using the Advanced Formatting option detailed here https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-tools/import-and-export-surveys/

I would like to be able to bring in an image URL with each question block and have the link display as a graphic. The documentation mentions there is a `[[Text]] or [[DB]] – Text/Graphic (Descriptive Block)` function but I can't figure out how to call it properly.

I have tried the following : (`\n` means new line below and there are no spaces)

`[[Question:Graphic]] \n https://cdn.britannica.com/s:300x300/55/174255-004-9A4971E9.jpg`

where I get a "Error Calling Service" message and

`[[Question:DB]] \n https://cdn.britannica.com/s:300x300/55/174255-004-9A4971E9.jpg`

and

`[[Question:DB:Graphic]] \n https://cdn.britannica.com/s:300x300/55/174255-004-9A4971E9.jpg`

However, it is only importing as a text question and not showing the URL as a graphic. The `Graphic` option for question type is not highlighted after importing (none of the circles are selected till I click something).

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import doesn't import images.  If you want to import the images into your Qualtrics library, you would have to import them separately by going to Library/Graphics.

Whether you import them into Qualtrics or not, you need to include the html to display the image in your question.  For example:

```
[[Question:DB]]
[[ID:Q1]]
<img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/s:300x300/55/174255-004-9A4971E9.jpg">
```